# I want to create a stats website for my discord bot and the users on my server but the redirect from discord does not work

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using node.js with following packages:
`discord-oauth2, jsonwebtoken, mongoose, express, ejs, cookie-parser`

My codes:
`<myurl> = localhost:2019`
`<myurl>/login :` https://pastebin.com/pt5bHq2L ;
`<myurl>/discordAuth :` https://pastebin.com/QUDK2gsT ;
`<myurl>/about/you :` https://pastebin.com/3GPJEmR2 ;
`parts of main.js :` https://pastebin.com/QTG2rwAL

My console.log as soon as i press "Authorize" at the Discord page i get redirected to from my /login page

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

DiscordHTTPError: 401 Unauthorized on GET /api/v9/users/@me
    at OAuth.request (D:\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\discord-oauth2\lib\eris\rest\RequestHandler.js:90:9)
    at OAuth.getUser (D:\Discord\NodeTestBot\node_modules\discord-oauth2\lib\oauth.js:145:15)
    at run (D:\Discord\NodeTestBot\randomsservicebotWS\js\DCRedirect.js:23:42)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Settings on Discord/Developers:
`Redirects = http://localhost:2019/discordAuth`